# Could not make tesseract works on Centos7

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I'm working on an app using Java Sprint with Maven in Eclipse.

I make tesseract works on my dev machine in Windows (yeah, I know...) but when I tried to deploy the app in the server which is a Centos 7, I get some errors and the app stop working...

pom.sml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
    <artifactId>tesseract-platform</artifactId>
    <version>3.04.01-1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

My code:

```
BytePointer outText;
                TessBaseAPI api = new TessBaseAPI();

                if (api.Init(ResourcesLocation.getTestData(), "spa") != 0) {
                    System.err.println("Could not initialize tesseract.");
                    response.setSuccess(false);
                    response.setCode(CodeList.EXCEPTION);
                }   
                else{
                    // Open input image with leptonica library
                    PIX image = pixRead(file);
                    api.SetImage(image);
                    // Get OCR result
                    outText = api.GetUNLVText();

                    data = this.cleanData(outText.getString().split("\\r?\\n"));
                    // Destroy used object and release memory
                    api.End();
                    outText.deallocate();
                    pixDestroy(image);
                }
                api.close();
```

And during runtime I get:

```
Estado HTTP 500 â€“ Internal Server Error

Tipo Informe de ExcepciÃ³n

mensaje Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

descripciÃ³n El servidor encontrÃ³ un error interno que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.

excepciÃ³n

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerErrororg.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1302)org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:977)org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)com.invoicebox.security.JWTTokenAuthFilter.doFilterInternal(JWTTokenAuthFilter.java:157)org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
causa raÃ­z

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerErrorjava.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:585)org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:530)org.bytedeco.javacpp.tesseract$TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(tesseract.java:3648)com.invoicebox.services.InvoiceServiceImpl.importInvoice(InvoiceServiceImpl.java:350)com.invoicebox.services.InvoiceServiceImpl.save(InvoiceServiceImpl.java:1422)sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1573.save(Unknown Source)com.invoicebox.controller.InvoiceController.save(InvoiceController.java:138)sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)com.invoicebox.security.JWTTokenAuthFilter.doFilterInternal(JWTTokenAuthFilter.java:157)org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
causa raÃ­z

java.lang.NullPointerExceptionorg.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.cacheResource(Loader.java:334)org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:772)org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:604)org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:530)org.bytedeco.javacpp.lept.<clinit>(lept.java:10)java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:585)org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:530)org.bytedeco.javacpp.tesseract$TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(tesseract.java:3648)com.invoicebox.services.InvoiceServiceImpl.importInvoice(InvoiceServiceImpl.java:350)com.invoicebox.services.InvoiceServiceImpl.save(InvoiceServiceImpl.java:1422)sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1573.save(Unknown Source)com.invoicebox.controller.InvoiceController.save(InvoiceController.java:138)sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)com.invoicebox.security.JWTTokenAuthFilter.doFilterInternal(JWTTokenAuthFilter.java:157)org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
nota La traza completa de la causa de este error se encuentra en los archivos de diario del servidor.
```

I installed Tesseract and Leptonica following [this example](https://github.com/EisenVault/install-tesseract-redhat-centos/blob/master/install-tesseract.sh) (but I changed the lenguage for spanish)

What I can get from there is that the app is crashing when doing:

```
TessBaseAPI api = new TessBaseAPI();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the final solution for this, was to run a command from the Java app in order to execute tesseract including the dessire params, and write the result on a text file. After that, the java app read the text file and that's all!

No API, no external libraries, no more problems...